# Is this a standard error from Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, nullpointerexception

I'm receiving this error while accessing in the index page of my JSP project.

```
Sep 3, 2013 12:03:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/MyProject] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root
cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I guess this is a "standard error" from TomCat but I can't find out what is the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `java.lang.NullPointerException` in your JSP page, but I take it you'd figured that out already.

JSP pages are converted/compiled to Java - thus the `(index_jsp.java:126)` in the stacktrace - but unfortunately you can't use the line number for figuring out the problem as it doesn't relate to your JSP file, but the resulting Java source.

You should, however, be able to figure out where the NPE happens by inspection, since your JSP is of course a thin presentation layer, right :-) A usual mistake could be referencing attributes that aren't provided on entry to the page, eg. `request.getParameter( "something" ).equals( "somethingelse" )` <-- possible NPE on `.equals()`

If you were to share the JSP page (perhaps in the form of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)), this community can help much better.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

It's not a "Tomcat standard"  error. Its an error in your source code. JSP is translated to java and `java.lang.NullPointerException` signifies that somewhere you are trying to use some variable without properly initializing it. Or you may have expected it to be initialized but it hasn't due to some resource being unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use the line number to find the error.  (The answer by Anders R. Bystrup incorrectly says the opposite "...unfortunately you can't use the line number for figuring out the problem".)

It's true the JSP pages are converted to Java and thus the line number does not correspond to the line number in your JSP, but you can find the converted Java file in your work directory, somewhere like:

```
${TOMCAT_HOME}/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java
```

and looking at the given line number (126) in that file should point you toward the problem in your JSP (there will likely be an identical line in your JSP).

As others have already pointed out, in this case you have an NPE.